# Bootstrap breakpoint viewport sizes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, cropperjs

I'm building a multi-device cropping tool using cropperjs. At the moment I'm guessing viewport sizes at each bootstrap breakpoint, but I'm not sure what the real height is (so I can create a ratio). You can find the grid width breakpoints here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss (lines 168-174)

To summarise, I'm looking for the viewport sizes at each breakpoint: `sm, md, lg, xl`. I could research the most common device size (I may still do this), but I'd prefer something that relates to bootstrap's sizing. Thank-you.

```
sm: {
    width: 576px,
    height: ...
}
md: {
    width: 768px,
    height: ...
}
lg: {
    width: 992px,
    height: ...
}
xl: {
    width: 1200px
    height: ...
}
```

Comment: `what the real height is` confuses me. Bootstrap's breakpoints do not consider `height` at all.

Comment: @RobertC I understand, but how did they pick those widths? They must have considered viewport heights when calculating those figures...

Comment: The breakpoints are loosely based on common viewport widths as explained by the author [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14894). The new breakpoint in 4.x is 576px [explained here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21333) but as you will see they're not exact, and independent of height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best option for this question is to use common ratios and calculate the viewport heights. Includes assumtions of the user's device.

i.e.

```
{
    xl: {
        width: 1200,
        height: 1200 * (9/16) // Landscape
    },
    lg: {
        width: 992,
        height: 992 * (9/16) // Landscape
    },
    md: {
        width: 768,
        height: 768 * (3/4) // Landscape
    },
    sm: {
        width: 576,
        height: 576 * (4/3) // Portrait
    }
}
```